# Problem with 2D Array of JButton

Tags: java, arrays, 2d, jbutton

I need to put number(2d array) on the top left of JButton. But, i got the number result in wrong ordder (upside down), not as the same as the array topLeftNum order. How to make it so the number will show up as the same order?Please help me solve my problem..Thanks

```
final int ROWS = 12;

final int COLS = 12;

final static int topLeftNum[][]= {
    {-1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 3, -1, 4, 0, 5, 0},
    {6, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1, -1, 0, -1},
    {-1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 7, 0, 0, 8, -1, 0, -1},
    {9, 0, 0, 0, 10, -1, -1, -1, 11, 0, 0, -1},
    {0, -1, -1, 12, 0, 0, 13, -1, 0, -1, -1, -1},
    {0, -1, 14, -1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 15, 0, 0, 16},
    {17, 0, 0, 18, 0, -1, 19, 20, 0, -1, -1, 0},
    {0, -1, 0, 0, -1, 21, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, 0},
    {22, 23, 0, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, -1,24, 0, 0},
    {-1, 0, -1, 25, 0, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, -1, -1},
    {26, 0, 0, -1, -1, 0, -1, 27, 0, 0, 0, -1},
    {-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, -1, -1}
    };

public static void main(String[] args){

  SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
     public void run(){
           new Lat1();
      }
   });
}

public Lat1() {
  //d = f.getText();
  //answer = d.charAt(0);
  this.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(ROWS, COLS));
  for (int j=0; j<ROWS; j++) {
    for (int i=0; i<COLS; i++)  {
       this.getContentPane().add(new Box(i, //the boxes index
                (topLeftNum[j][i] < 0) ? Color.BLACK : Color.WHITE, //pick the color
                topLeftNum[j][i], //the topleft number
                (char)(65+i), //the char inside
                this), //the action listener for the button
                i); //the index to place it on the container
       }
    }
    this.pack();
    this.setVisible(true);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> i); //the index to place it on the container

this line is the problem, remove "i" and it works fine.

Comment: @PaulSullivan: the user who asked the question doesn't even exist anymore 0_0